# How to save the version from the last published version of a lambda function

Tags: bash, aws-lambda

I would like to save the version from the last published lambda I have. I found this code where I can get as output the last published version.

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --no-paginate \
  --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(to_number(Version) || '0'))"
```

Do you know how can I save from here into a bash script the version of this output to use it later in the script. Thank you.

Comment: What have you searched for tried so far? Have a look at bash command substitution. Something like `last_published_lambda_version="$(your aws cli cmd)"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, I solved it in this way:

```
PUBLISHED_VERSION=$(aws lambda publish-version \
        --function-name "${FUNCTION_NAME}" \
        --description "${LATEST_TAG}")

VERSION=$(echo ${PUBLISHED_VERSION} | python3 -c "import sys,json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['Version'])")
```